# Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/addon' after deploying to docker container

Tags: node.js, node-modules, heap-dump

I am using below versions.
node -v
v8.16.0
heapdump : 0.3.12

The below error is getting once I deploy the code to docker container. The local setup is working fine without this issue.

Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/addon'

Kindly help on this issue.